# How to copy text to the clipboard in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm wondering if there's any way to copy text to the clipboard. I'm well aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript), but it's over three years old now. Has anything changed since then?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't four years old... **:-)**

Comment: But the question was asked in 2008. =)

Comment: Pish tosh, 2012 - 2008 = 4. Everybody knows that. :P (joking aside, you're right, of course. Fixing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do at this point is to go with a Flash based solution. [zeroclipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/) is a common one (a nice walkthrough is available [here](http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard)).

Browser vendors have over the past few years removed programatic access to the clipboard. Safari / Chrome lost the ability after a change in WebKit, and FireFox for a long time has blocked it. Only IE remains as one that does allow it, however it displays an alert on each page initially.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```js
function myFunc() {
  /* Get the text field */
  let copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");

  /* Select the text field */
  copyText.select();

  /* Copy the text inside the text field */
  document.execCommand("copy");

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .60rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #007bff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- The text field -->
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="Some Random Text">

<!-- The button used to copy the text -->
<button type="button" onclick="myFunc()">Copy</button>
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer? document.exe('copy') was already used in the referred question